# MVC - Pass ViewModel to View using c#

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel as such:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{


    Employees employee{ get; set; }
    Budget budget { get; set; }



}
```

I like to pass this view model to a view that does a create that requires both of the tables.

I tried doing the following in the controller that would pass information to the view but was not successful:

```
    EmployeeViewModel pvm = new EmployeeViewModel()
    return View(pvm);
```

The reason being is that the Value of both employee and budget it null. 
How do I pass this information to the view so it knows about both of the tables?

Comment: Please don't take offense. I don't see any initialization of the Employees or Budget....is it happening in the constructor?

Comment: Can you give more information about your view?  Are you getting page errors, or is nothing happening?  When you say tables, I assume you mean the tables in the database that your Employees and Budget Models correspond to?  when you say: "...does a create...", do you mean an insert into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this, you will have references in the ViewModel properties:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    Employees employee { get; set; }
    Budget budget { get; set; }

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
         employee = ... initialize Employee list/set...
         budget = ... initialize budget
    }

}
```

If Employees and Budgets are LINQ/ADO EF models, you could attach data from database in a controller:

```
public class BudgetController : Controller {

  public ViewResult Index() {
    var db = new YourContextClass();
    EmployeeViewModel pvm = new EmployeeViewModel();
    pvm.employees = db.Employees.All(); // or some where condition
    pvm.budget = db.Budget.FirstOrDefault(b=> b.Year == DateTime.Now.Year); // if you have Year property in budget model
    return View(pvm);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's what I asked in the comments...never got an answer back LOL